# Joomla 1.7.5 to 2.5 Migration - When not showing any updates about 2.5

Tags: joomla, migration, joomla1.7

I tried to migrate my Joomla 1.7 website to Joomla 2.5.14 stable version. But when I look for updates in admin end, it shows there is not updates found for new release. I couldn't find any upgrade patch, so I simply follow the below steps.

1. Take backup of Joomla 1.7 website including DB for safety.
2. Download new Joomla 2.5.14 and extract the files.
3. Copy all the files from Joomla 2.5.14.
4. Paste all the files to Joomla 1.7 (it must overwrite with existing files, do not delete all of the files from Joomla 1.7).
5. No need to modify the database.
6. And finally check admin end by login and preview your site.

Answer (score 0):

This is a good start.

After that sometimes I have found that going to **extensions -> db -> fix** had some work to do.

This will get Joomla up to date (although you will have some leftover files, not a big deal).  But it will **not** install the new features such as Joomla update icon in the control panel.

In order to do that you need to repackage the extensions, remove the files from the installation, and reinstall.  It may take a few tries (you need to remove the language files and any off-folder files as well, either from the disk - and putting them in the installation zip - or from the `.xml` manifest.

The three extensions I found I wanted most were `com_joomlaupdate`, and the `extensionupdate` and `joomlaupdate` plugins. You can download them from [this page](http://www.fasterjoomla.com/joomla-dev/upgrade-from-joomla-17-to-25): 
it also contains the list of files which you should delete:

```
rm -rf administrator/components/com_joomlaupdate
rm -rf plugins/quickicon/extensionupdate
rm -rf plugins/quickicon/joomlaupdate
rm administrator/language/en-GB/en-GB.com_joomlaupdate.ini
rm administrator/language/en-GB/en-GB.com_joomlaupdate.sys.ini
rm administrator/language/en-GB/en-GB.com_joomlaupdate.ini
rm administrator/language/en-GB/en-GB.com_joomlaupdate.sys.ini
rm administrator/language/en-GB/en-GB.plg_quickicon_extensionupdate.ini
rm administrator/language/en-GB/en-GB.plg_quickicon_extensionupdate.sys.ini
rm administrator/language/en-GB/en-GB.plg_quickicon_joomlaupdate.ini
rm administrator/language/en-GB/en-GB.plg_quickicon_joomlaupdate.sys.ini
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend Admin Tools for updating Joomla: https://www.akeebabackup.com/downloads/admin-tools.html

Comment: I would not. Broke everything in my case.

Comment: Meanwhile I know why. Templates from 1.7.3 don't work with 3.x, and there are many other incompatibilities between them. So better check elaboratly if you plan on updating Joomla.

Comment: Migrating the templates is a pretty straightforward task. Check out http://magazine.joomla.org/issues/issue-may-2012/item/740-How-to-convert-Joomla-15-template-to-Joomla-25